# Blink animation using camera2 api after clicking a picture

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android

I want to have some sort of animation when user clicks an image. I tried adding `Blink` animation to texureView but it keeps blinking. Below is the code:

```
Animation animation;
mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.texture);
animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(Activity,Resource.Animation.blink);
mTextureView.StartAnimation(animation);

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

I basically want a default click effect which occurs when you click an image by going to the camera app. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why you need this _android:repeatCount="infinite"_?

Comment: What should it be then?

Comment: Have you tried without it? Does it give same output?

Comment: If I remove it then it does not work

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?